# How to join 2 tables in django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I have 2 models which i wanna join

```
class CollectionBook(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey('Collection')
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('collection', 'book'))


class Book(models.Model):
    main_author = models.ForeignKey('Author', verbose_name=u'Main author')
    publisher = models.ForeignKey('Publisher', verbose_name=u'Publisher')
    title = models.CharField(unique=False, max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Title')
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name=u'Book text', max_length=523000)
```

I tried to do it this way

```
book = Book.objects.extra(
                    select = {'id':'mainapp_collectionbook.book_id'})
book.query.join((None,'mainapp_collectionbook',None,None))

connection = (
      Book._meta.db_table,
      CollectionBook.book.field,
)
book.query.join(connection, promote=True)
```

But it didn't work out and gave me error
Could you offer me another pythonic solutions of this problem or improve my way of doing it, I don't wanna write sql query, I hope that there are better django orm functions for this

Comment: please, write what logic for query set data do you want?

Comment: I have another table "Collection". I want select books where  collection to which book belongs is in allowed collection list. I generate collection list before this query

Answer (score 1):

Taking the clarification from the comment:

> I have another table "Collection". I want select books where collection to which book belongs is in allowed collection list. I generate collection list before this query

First, replace your explicit `CollectionBook` table with a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) on either `Book` or `Collection`. For this example I'll assume it's on `Book`, since that keeps the syntax clearer and the `Collection` model isn't shown.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    main_author = models.ForeignKey('Author', verbose_name=u'Main author')
    publisher = models.ForeignKey('Publisher', verbose_name=u'Publisher')
    title = models.CharField(unique=False, max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Title')
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name=u'Book text', max_length=523000)
    collection = models.ManyToManyField('Collection')
```

Then you can use `__` syntax to follow relationships:

```
Books.objects.filter(collection__in=SOME_LIST_OF_COLLECTIONS).distinct()
```

If you need additional information on the book/collection relation, EG a date collected or something, specify a [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) argument to the `ManyToManyField`.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you can try it, but don't forget to change the `YOU_CONDITION`

```
allow_collections = CollectionBook.objects.filter(YOU_CONDITION)
books_pks = allow_collections.values_list('book__pk', flat=true)

Book.objects.filter(pk__in=books_pks)
```